# How to set div in center vertically and horizontally where height is not known?

Tags: html, css

This is my login form in reactjs and I want to try set this login form in center vertically and horizontally, and `width is 35% and height is unknown` so I am trying to set this form in center and I use `margin : auto` but it set only in horizontally center not vertically so how to do that ?

HTML

```
    <div className="login-form">
        <Input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" />
        <Input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" />
        <Button type="primary" name="submit">Log in</Button>
      </Card>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
login-form {
  width: 35%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: vertically relative to what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is not possible to vertically center a block with this technique, only horizontal centering is allowed
try this css code to get a vertical and horizontal centering:

```
login-form {
 width: 35%;
 margin: auto;
 margin-top: 50vh; /*allow us to push the login-form into the half of the viewport */
 transform: translateY(-50%);
```

/*the login-form will shoot the half of his own height*/
}

hope this will work for you 
good luck

Comment: You could replace ```margin-top:50vh;``` with ```position:absolute;left:50%;top:50%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%); ``` for better compatibility with older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of possible approaches. You can use container element for your login form as flexbox container:

```css
/* Pure visual styles */
.container {
  max-width: 300px;
  min-height: 300px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
.login-form {
  width: 35%;
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}

/* Centering */
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="login-form"></div>
</div>
```

Alternatively you can use absolute positioning and `transform`:

```css
/* Pure visual styles */
.container {
  max-width: 300px;
  min-height: 300px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
.login-form {
  width: 35%;
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}

/* Centering */
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.login-form {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="login-form"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: but my width is in percentage and I apply your code it not works kindly help me

Comment: @Akki I've updated answer to have `width` to be defined as `35%` and it works properly